# puppet node hostname

Tags: hostname, puppet

I'm using puppet to configure servers. I want to print current machine (node) name in *.erb template. There is *hostname* variable, but this holds puppetmaster hostname. Is there any good reference/list regarding to this topic?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Seems like I have miss-looked somewhere. I can get(print) node-hostname simply by invoking following code in *.erb template:

```
<%= @hostname %>
```

Edit: As of Puppet 3, using local variables (i.e. `hostname` is deprecated; Puppet 4 will remove support for them entirely.  The recommended way is to use instance variables (prefixed with `@`.  So in this case, `@hostname`.  [Source](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html)

Comment: ah exactly, I was really puzzled, because in my case for "fqdn" I get the full hostname (like "myhost.acnemcom"), while for "hostname" I get the short version (the one returned by the command hostname -s) , like "myhost". In no case I get the puppetmaster host.

Answer (score 32):

Entering the following command into your terminal will return variables available in your erb files:

```
facter --puppet
```

Comment: This answer shows that I don't want 'hostname' but 'fqdn' instead form my application.

Answer (score 6):

Yes to all the above; you may also find the `fqdn` variable useful, depending on what you're up to.

If you DO find yourself needing the puppet master server's info in a template, you can use the variables `servername`, `serverip`, and `serverversion` ([From the Puppet docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.10/lang_facts_builtin_variables.html#server-facts)).

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can now use

```
<%= fqdn %>
```

and get the DNS reverse name.

If you need to lowercase it, use

```
<%= fqdn.downcase %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do note though, this is the hostname rather than the node name (which you originally asked for). In 99% of cases, these will be the same. AFAIK there isn't a way to get the actual node name in templates (and if there is, I'd love to hear it).