# Puppet erb hostname returns servername

Tags: puppet, hostname

I want  to put the node name in a template. I was expecting the variable @hostname to do so but I get  the servername instead.

The master node is a debian wheezy with puppet 3.7.5-1puppetlabs1, the node is wheezy with puppet 2.7.23-1~deb7u3.

I tried this template:

```
hostname=<%= @hostname %>
fqdn=<%= @fqdn %>
servername=<%= @servername %>
```

I go to the node and I type:

```
# puppet agent --test
```

And that is what is generated:

```
hostname=puppet

fqdn=enquestes.my.domain
servername=puppet.my.domain
```

I was expecting hostname would return *enquestes*, and that is what I understand reading this other question:

[puppet node hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428153/puppet-node-hostname)

So I wonder if there is something messed up somewhere. Notice the extra newline after the ''puppet'' hostname. It was not in the template but it gets written in the output. I tried also with:

```
inline_template('<%= hostname %>')
```

But it returns *puppet* instead of the node hostname as I expected.

If I go to the node and I type this:

```
$ facter | grep -i hostname
```

I get the expected hostname *enquestes*. So I wonder maybe I missed something and this is the expected behaviour or is there something wrong in my node or master ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I found in the manifest I had this from a previous try $hostname   = generate('/usr/bin/env','/bin/hostname'). I didn't know it was going in the template. I just commented it and now I get an empty hostname when I run puppet agent. I was exepecting now to get the node name

Comment: Perhaps you're obliterating the variable value in some other scope as well?

Comment: Good point, then it should be in one manifests or template ? I tried grep -i hostname * and it shows nothing.

Comment: Grep through *all* manifests to be on the safe side.

Comment: After 24 hours it works as expected. I guess the @hostname was kept in memory or cached somehow.